# Perl: Compare 2 hash table values

Tags: perl

Kindly advice how to compare key value pair between two hashes.
Basically I want to check if hash1 keyvalue pair exists in hash2.

Thanks

Comment: This pops up all the time on SO -- have you searched for existing questions on the topic?

Comment: you mean same key *and* same value?  just check if there are *any*?  or get a list of ones that are the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@pataka : I am not printing twice but doing comparison for both alpha-numeric strings . So i have printed one for stings and another for numbers . We can do the same even in this way as shown below:

```
    #Same Key and Value
foreach my $val1 (keys %hash1)
 {
      foreach my $val2 (keys %hash2)   {

             if($val1 eq $val2)        {
                  if($hash1{$val1} eq $hash2{$val2}) {
                    print "Key:$val1\t" ;
                    print "Value:$hash1{$val1}\n";

                      }   
                  }  
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

@pataka: Look into the below code if it is helpful:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash1 = ( 'Jan' => 1 , 'Feb' => "abc" , 'Mar' => 3);
my %hash2 = ( 'Jan' => 85 , 'Feb' => 44 , 'Mar' => 3 , 'Apr' => 23);


#Same key
foreach my $val1 (keys %hash1)
 {
      foreach my $val2 (keys %hash2)   {
             if($val1 eq $val2)        {
                 print $val1 . "\n"; 
                  }
                }
        }        

#Same Value
foreach my $val1 (values %hash1)
 {
      foreach my $val2 (values %hash2)   {
             if($val1 eq $val2)        {
                 print $val1 . "\n"; 
                  }
                }
        }   

#Same Key and Value
foreach my $val1 (keys %hash1)
 {
      foreach my $val2 (keys %hash2)   {
             if($val1 eq $val2 && $val1 =~ m/\d+/)         {
                  if($hash1{$val1} == $hash2{$val2}) {
                    print $val1; 
                      }
                  }
             if($val1 eq $val2 && $val1 =~ m/[A-za-z ]+/)          {
                  if($hash1{$val1} eq $hash2{$val2}) {
                    print $val1; 
                      }   
                  }  
                }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Praveen... I am confused which 1 should I select from above anwsers. In my case I want to find exact key value pair macthes in another hash table then print key and value both... I think I should go for #Same Key and Value  ... but why are you printing val1 twice and to print key should i use  $hash1{$val1} ...Please advice